# Entity Framework CTP Code First column naming and relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, ef-code-first

I just started looking at the new Entity Framework CTP5 code first bits.

I have the following very simple entities.

```
User
 int Id;
 Account Account;

Account
 int Id;
 User AccountOwner;
 ICollection<User> Users;
```

So, accounts have an owner(User) and can have many users. These relationships is translated to an `Accounts` table and an `Users` table int the DB.

In the Users table I get two collumns, `AccountId` and `AccountId1`, is there any way to control the generated names for those columns. Also I would actually expect there to be a `UserId` column for the `AccountOwner` property on the `Accounts` table, but it seems that the reference is on the `Users` table instead. It would be really nice NOT to the have `AccountId...n` for all the keys :)

Comment: why does the specific user have multiple accounts ?

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things going on here.

In the case of User and Account having 1:1 relationships with each other it's choosing the side you don't want. There's no way for it to know which side to put it on without you telling it so you can tell it either with the fluent API or with an attribute.  It's likely you want to make one side optional and one required which will force the FK to the other side, e.g.

```
User
...
[Optional]
Account Account;

Account
...
[Required]
User AccountOwner;
```

Alternatively you can use the fluent API:

```
config.Entity<User>().HasOptional(u => u.Account).WithRequired(a => a.AccountOwner)
```

If you follow intellisense on that you can also use the constraint property to wire up the FK properties too.

To rename the FK properties if they're still not what you like either use the Column attribute, e.g.

```
User
[Column(Name="Id")]
int Id;
```

Or again with the fluent API:

```
config.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
```